# how to get Youtube songs list with youtube api?

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

I want get youtube videos list from keyword.
If I search "html", it will get more than 10 videos named with "html".
I thought it requires Youtube API.

Answer (score 0):

**I thought it requires YouTube API.**

For clarification purposes, use of the YouTube API is basically required if you want to integrate YouTube videos and other functionalities into your website or application. If you want to search YouTube videos or songs list from within your app, you can do so with the use of the YouTube API.

With regards to retrieving YouTube videos/songs list, you may want to use [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). This method:

> Returns a collection of search results that match the query parameters specified in the API request. By default, a search result set identifies matching [video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), [channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels), and [playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists) resources, but you can also configure queries to only retrieve a specific type of resource.

Simply send HTTP request using this format:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search
```

and to further trim down your search results, you may use optional parameters such as `type` with the following acceptable values:

- channel
- playlist
- video

Please see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) for more information.